# Inverted Sigmoid Curve

Tags: curves

I want to find a function $f$ that has an inverted sigmoid-like curve and one other constraint: $f(0) = 1$

I've inverted the sigmoid like this: $1- \dfrac{1}{(1 + \exp(-x))}$ but don't know how to do with the constraint.

**NB**: no matter if the function is defined for $x<0$ or not.

Comment: Multiply by 2 to the one you got.

Comment: this will not gives me sigmoid-like function from 0 to +inf